# Two structure having same variable

Tags: c

I have to write 2 structures, like this:

```
typedef struct { 
    const char max ; 
    char *val ; 
    const char *charray ; 
    const char *entstate ; 
    const char *entindex ; 
    const char escstate ; 
    const char escindex ; 
} choice ;

typedef struct { 
    const int min ; 
    const int max ; 
    int *val ; 
    const char entstate ; 
    const char entindex ; 
    const char escstate ; 
    const char escindex ; 
} remote ;
```

But this is showing an error, ie some of variable like `escstate`, `escindex`, etc. These identifiers are already used in this code. This error is shown because `enstate` is already being defined in structure `choice`, and it's defined again in structure `remote`. But I need all these variables in structure `remote`. What is the solution for it?

Comment: I just pasted your code to a test file and it compiled without error...

Comment: Please, paste a minimal compilable source. Also include the exact error message you're seeing from your compiler.

Comment: no, the problem is not your structs, likely it is your code, how you are trying to use them, but you show no anything else. struct (even anopnymous) member names do not collide.

Comment: how about your code? can you post it too? in 'choise' the 'enststate' is a pointer but in 'remote' is not. i hope you handle them differently.

Comment: but it is showing error in my case. can be d problem related to compiler...i mean it may be compiler specific...hm?

Comment: Actually my code is very lengthy..bt i can post a part of code which uses that stuctures.

Comment: At least, post the compilation error you got, and the line which triggered it. And if you think it may be compiler specific - why not tell us which compiler you use?

Comment: "i mean it may be compiler specific" -- Not unless you've stepped into a time machine and are using a Unix version 6 compiler.

Comment: I am using  CCS PICC COMPILER...that was only the part of the code tht was dealing with C concepts hence asked here.

Answer (score 3):

> these identifier are already used in dis code

Structure fields are in different namespaces - that can't be the problem. You can even have global variables with the same names as the fields. I find the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/namespace.html) is very clear on this subject:

> There are four different kinds of namespaces, for:
>
> - labels (i.e. goto targets);
> - tags (names of structures, unions, and enumerations; these three    aren't separate even though they theoretically could be);
> - structure/union members (**one namespace per structure or union**);
> - everything else (functions, variables, typedef names, enumeration    constants), termed ``ordinary identifiers'' by the Standard